# Flutter: Android instrumentation test - how to provide no sound null safety argument to gradlew command

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-instrumentation

While working with integration tests for a flutter app (which is currently in migration stage to sound null safety), the `gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=<path_to_test>.dart` command failed with an error

> Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using
> sound null safety.

As per the [documentation from flutter repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#firebase-test-lab) , this step is required to generate a test apk that can be later uploaded to firebase test lab.

Is there a way to pass `--no-sound-null-safety argument` to the `gradlew` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to pass the `--no-sound-null-safety` argument to the `gradlew` command as this is a flutter feature.

The workaround was to make the entry point of the app file use dart 2.9 which is non null safety type.

```
// @dart=2.9

void main(){
    
}
```

On making the `main()` entry file for the integration test, the `gradlew` command was able to assemble the app without any additional commands.